# Finviz.com Web scraping headers through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

through help from other questions that I have posted in the forum I can extract all the information from the 3 tabs (Overview, valuation and Financials) in the finviz screener. However I can't seem to get the top row populated with the headers (Ticker, EPS, P/E, Market Cap etc) for all the information extracted. Any suggestions?

```
Public Sub Initial()
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111", 1, 11, 0
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=121", 13, 10, 3
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161", 23, 10, 3
End Sub


Public Sub FetchTabularData(ByVal Url As String, ByVal StartColumn As Long, AmountOfColumns As Long, ByVal StartChildren As Long)
    Const base$ = "https://finviz.com/"
    Dim elem As Object, S$, R&, oPage As Object, nextPage$
    Dim Http As Object, Html As Object, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set Html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
 
R = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do While Url <> vbNullString
    DoEvents
    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With Html
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then
                R = R + 1
                
                ' prepare an temporary array to write the row data into
                Dim TempRow() As Variant
                ReDim TempRow(1 To 1, 1 To AmountOfColumns) As Variant
                
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 0 To AmountOfColumns - 1
                    ' instead of writing to the cells directly
                    ' ws.Cells(R, StartColumn + i) = elem.Children(StartChildren + i).innerText
                    ' we write into the temp array
                    TempRow(1, i + 1) = elem.Children(StartChildren + i).innerText
                Next i
                
                ' and write the entire row at once (10 times faster than writing each cell)
                ws.Cells(R, StartColumn).Resize(ColumnSize:=AmountOfColumns).Value = TempRow
            End If
        Next elem
        
        Url = vbNullString
        For Each oPage In .getElementsByTagName("a")
            If InStr(oPage.className, "tab-link") And InStr(oPage.innerText, "next") > 0 Then
                nextPage = oPage.getAttribute("href")
                Url = base & Replace(nextPage, "about:", "")
            End If
        Next oPage
    End With
Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The header row uses `table-top` class name which will fail in this statement: `If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then`, try adding another `InStr` check for `table-top` in the `If-Then` statement.

Comment: doesn't seem to work even after adding [InStr(elem.className, "table-top") > 0]

Comment: Ah sorry, that class is in the `td` tag, not `tr` tag which you are looping through. @Mafoola

Comment: 1) Change `For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("tr")` to `For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("table")(3).getElementsByTagName("tr")` so you are looping the `tr` elements in the table directly. 2) Remove the `If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then` and the `End If` statement since you do not need it anymore (you already are looping the intended table's `tr` itself) @Mafoola

Comment: Hey Raymond, thanks for the tip the top row is being picked. However every time the code goes to a new page the header row is being picked again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish up from my comments - To get the header row, we loop through all the `tr` tag in the specific table instead and use `If Not elem.PreviousSibling Is Nothing Or nextPage = vbNullString Then` to avoid additional header row in the subsequent pages.

Full code below:

```
Public Sub Initial()
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111", 1, 11, 0
    'FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=121", 13, 10, 3
    'FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161", 23, 10, 3
End Sub


Public Sub FetchTabularData(ByVal Url As String, ByVal StartColumn As Long, AmountOfColumns As Long, ByVal StartChildren As Long)
    Const base$ = "https://finviz.com/"
    Dim elem As Object, S$, R&, oPage As Object, nextPage$
    Dim Http As Object, Html As Object, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set Html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
 
R = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do While Url <> vbNullString
    DoEvents
    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With Html
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("table")(3).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If Not elem.PreviousSibling Is Nothing Or nextPage = vbNullString Then
                R = R + 1
                
                ' prepare an temporary array to write the row data into
                Dim TempRow() As Variant
                ReDim TempRow(1 To 1, 1 To AmountOfColumns) As Variant
                
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 0 To AmountOfColumns - 1
                    ' instead of writing to the cells directly
                    ' ws.Cells(R, StartColumn + i) = elem.Children(StartChildren + i).innerText
                    ' we write into the temp array
                    TempRow(1, i + 1) = elem.Children(StartChildren + i).innerText
                Next i
                
                ' and write the entire row at once (10 times faster than writing each cell)
                ws.Cells(R, StartColumn).Resize(ColumnSize:=AmountOfColumns).Value = TempRow
            End If
        Next elem
        
        Url = vbNullString
        For Each oPage In .getElementsByTagName("a")
            If InStr(oPage.className, "tab-link") And InStr(oPage.innerText, "next") > 0 Then
                nextPage = oPage.getAttribute("href")
                Url = base & Replace(nextPage, "about:", "")
            End If
        Next oPage
    End With
Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome works beautifully

Comment: Please accept the answer since it resolves your problem. @mafoola